# Running two Java Web Apps targeting separate JREs on the same PC

Tags: java

I access two Java Web Apps that were developed using different versions (1.6 and 1.8) of Java and have Applets.  How can I use them both on the same PC?

I believe that if they were client applications then I could run Java.exe manually e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe MyApp.  Is that correct?

How do I do this with WebApps? I have tried changing the version of Java to 1.6 in the Control Panel as follows:

[image]

However, the 1.6 app does not run with this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can set java version for each project in project conf files

in *pom.xml* for maven

```
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <configuration>
      <!-- or whatever version you use -->
      <source>1.7 <!--required version--></source>
      <target>1.7 <!--required version--></target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
...
```

or in *build.xml* for ant project

```
<target name="compile">
  <javac target="1.5" srcdir=.../>
</target>
```